# How to evaluate this triple integral?

Tags: integration, calculus

i am solving a physics problem in which i've found this integral,  i tried  but i can not imagine a possible change of variable, probably it is necessary to calculate it numerically..but i would like to reduce it a little bit before to do it.
Thanks for your help!
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2\alpha\sqrt{\rho_2^2+z_2^2}}e^{-2\alpha \sqrt{\rho_1^2+z_1^2}}}{ \sqrt{4\rho_1^2\rho_2^2-(\rho_1^2+\rho_2^2-\rho_{12}^2)^2}\sqrt{\rho_{12}^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}}\rho_1\rho_2\rho_{12}\mathrm{d}\rho_1\mathrm{d}\rho_2\mathrm{d}\rho_{12}\,.
$$

Comment: Try to join the exponents and the square roots. Solving that might be even impossible, buy try Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Might [math.se]  be better suited for this math question?

Comment: Well, changing to $u_i=\sqrt{\rho_i^2+z_i^2}$ probably wouldn't hurt. With that, at least one of the $\rho_i$ becomes of the form $\int_a^\infty \mathrm du \: e^{-u}/\sqrt{u+b}$, which is likely to be e.g. in §3.36 of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. So, in that vein: what have you tried?

Comment: I tried first to perform the integral of $ ρ_{12}$  I put $ ρ^2_{12}+(z2−z1)^2$  as a new variable.. but is still dificult to perform the integral

Comment: Are you sure that in the expression $\:(\rho_1^2+\rho_2^2-\rho_{12})\:$ under the 1rst square root in the denominator the term $\:\rho_{12}\:$ doesn't need to be squared $\:\rho_{12}^2\:$??? If not, then there exists a dimensionality incompatibility if for example the variables $\:\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_{12}\:$ and the constants $\:z_1,z_2\:$ have dimension of Length.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have already edited the question...thank you

Comment: Are you sure of $4\rho_1^2\rho_2^2-(\rho_1^2+\rho_2^2-\rho_{12}^2)^2$ in the square root ? It is negative or nul for some values of the variables. This makes locally the denominator complex or nul.